# Undefined method it_behaves_like / it_should_behave_like / include_examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm getting undefined method for it_behaves_like, it_should_behave_like and include_examples.

The test is on spec/features. I'm including the file with the shared_examples/shared_examples_for.

What's going on?

Comment: Please copy and paste the specs as well as the shared examples into your question above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was that I had the it_behaves_like inside an `it "..." do` and not a `describe "..." do`. I didn't notice it because it was a slow integration test and I had a few assertions inside the "it" block. Preparing an example for aceofbassgreg made me realize the error.